# building glib gives error: gfileutils.c:57:25: error: linux/magic.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gtk, centos, glib

I am on CentOS 5.5 and I am getting the error above when running make in the glib 2.27 directory. What is magic.h and what should I do to correct this?

Also - is there an easier way to get gtk installed on centos?

Answer (score 2):

CentOS package repositories already contain GTK+ 2.10 and GLib 2.12 packages. Unless you specifically need a newer version, just install the distro packages:

```
yum install gtk2-devel
```

If these versions are too old for your development work, consider upgrading to a distro which ships with newer GTK+ stack like Fedora 14.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a /usr/include/linux directory?  Does it contain a magic.h header file?  If not, you probably need to install the "kernel-headers" package.